# Can I build a portal on top of the Nether in Minecraft Windows 10?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I just got on top of the nether using an ender pearl glitch in Minecraft Windows 10. But now I can't build my portal! I'm getting an error that says "the build limit is 128 blocks." Is there anything I can do to change that? Just to make it 5 blocks higher and put a portal up there?

This is for Minecraft Windows 10 edition, which I believe is the same as Bedrock

Comment: If this answer worked for you, please click the green check button to the left so everyone knows that the problem is solved.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, you cannot build above the nether roof on Bedrock Edition. To do so, you must edit the game code, which I will not go into much detail. However, in Java Edition, the build limit is 256 blocks in the nether.

Putting portals up there is impossible in Bedrock Edition, but phasing/breaking bedrock at spots directly above your portals can help with travel, as you can go to the roof, and run to another destination with ease. I hope this helps.

Comment: Wait, then how do I see multiplayer servers with portals on top of the nether? Hermitcraft, for instance.

Comment: @Corsaka This is because Hermitcraft and such are playing on **Java Edition**, not bedrock, where the limit is 256, not 128.

Comment: Ah, I thought you were continuing talking about JE. Apologies.